# I need to find the current through the diodes

Tags: diodes

[image: Diodes]

I need to find the current through the diodes, but I don't know if I should use the resistance of 180 ohm when I calculate the current WITH the 150 ohm load.

I have an answer but I don't know if it's right.

I calculated without the load current = 5-1.3/180, and that's equal to 20.5 mA. And with the load I calculated 5-1.3/(180+150). But I don't know if it is only 5-1.3/150 because V<sub>o</sub> is taking only the diodes and the 150 ohm load.

Comment: Thevenize your two resistors into a single new voltage source magnitude and series resistance. Subtract the two diode voltages from the new voltage source value. Divide this result by the new source resistance to get the diode current.

Answer (score 2):

With or without the 150 Ω resistor connected, the diodes are conducting some current and producing a total volt-drop of 1.3 volts. Do you see why the diodes must be conducting?

- Given a volt drop of 3.7 volts across the 180 Ω resistor, you can calculate its current.
- And, given that there is 1.3 volts across the 150 Ω resistor you can calculate its current.

Can you take it from here to calculate the diode current?

Comment: Thank you so much, can you tell me please if my answer is right? without the 150 load =20,55 mA. And WITH the 150 load ID= 8,6mA. Please.

Comment: Hint to the OP: there are three currents in this circuit, the current in the diodes, the current in the 180 Ohm resistor, and the current in the 150 Ohm resistor. You can use Kirchoff's Current Law to write an equation about the three currents.

Comment: @Ranjitnapulasem the diode current is the 180 ohm current minus the 150 ohm current.

Comment: @Andyaka thank you so much

Comment: @Ranjitnapulasem you should take the [2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand why folk give their time for free to help others.

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned Thevenizing the resistor pair. All that means is ignoring the diodes for the moment, just look at the voltage supply rail and the two resistors. Here you find that \$V_{_\text{TH}}=5\:\text{V}\frac{150\:\Omega}{150\:\Omega+180\:\Omega}=2.\overline{27}\:\text{V}\$ and that \$R_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{150\:\Omega\,\cdot\, 180\:\Omega}{150\:\Omega+180\:\Omega}=81.\overline{81}\:\Omega\$.

This supplies the two diodes in the case where the \$150\:\Omega\$ is connected up.

So with the \$150\:\Omega\$ connected up, we have \$\frac{2.\overline{27}\:\text{V}-2\,\cdot\,650\:\text{mV}}{81.\overline{81}\:\Omega}= 11.\overline{8}\:\text{mA}\$ for the diode current.

Witout the \$150\:\Omega\$ connected up, we have \$\frac{5\:\text{V}-2\,\cdot\,650\:\text{mV}}{180\:\Omega}= 20.\overline{5}\:\text{mA}\$ for the diode current.

That's all there is to it.